# Is there Eclipse's Ctrl+3 equivalent in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse

Ctrl+3 in Eclipse can do this:

http://techvj.blogspot.com/2007/11/any-software-developer-using-ide-begins.html

Is there an equivalent in Visual Studio? Or via some 3rd party plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Microsoft's Productivity Power Tools Extension.

[image: PPT Quick Access]

Comment: I apologize to the low res folks.

Answer (score 0):

For source file switching, you can also hit Ctrl-Alt-Down arrow and type to switch to an open file.  You can also use the find combo box on the toolbar by clicking on it or hitting Ctrl-/ then typing  '>of'.  A list of all files in the solution appears in the dropdown and you can type to select a file to edit.

To build on what VonC said, in addition to Ctrl-Tab, you can hit Alt-F7 to bring up that same window dialog but have the starting selection be the first tools window.  Again, though, not as complete as what Eclipse may have.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably: no, there currently isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=Home) (Productivity Power tools) that has exactly what we were looking for. It's even called quick access and is called with ctrl+3.

Answer (score -1):

If you limit yourself to just Visual Studio, you do have a *limited* "quick access" shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: [Quick Access to Active Tool Windows and Files](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/VS2005ActiveWindows07312005140244PM/VS2005ActiveWindows.aspx) (from VS2005!)

[image: quick access]

Mostly for tool access and file switching, so in itself not as complete than Eclipse Quick Access list.

Comment: Ctrl+3 is very good for feature discovery so I don't really consider this VS dialog an alternative although it is a creative answer :)

Comment: @Borek: I agree and never presented that as a real "alternative".